# is there are a method to build subgroups of the multiplicative group $\left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^*$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, arithmetic, totient-function, maximal-subgroup

The multiplicative group $\left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^*$ is  defined by : $ \left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^*=
 \{\, \bar{x} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\;\;:\;\;gcd(x,n)=1 \,\}
 $
then we have :
$$
 \left( \mathbb{Z}/50\mathbb{Z}\right)^*= \{\,
 \bar{1},\bar{3},\bar{7},\bar{9},\bar{11},\bar{13},\bar{17},\bar{19},\bar{21},\bar{23},\bar{27},\bar{29},\bar{31},\bar{33},\bar{37}
 ,\bar{39},\bar{41},\bar{43},\bar{47},\bar{49} \,\}
 $$
then the set
$$\mathbb{E} = \{\,\bar{1},\bar{11},\bar{21},\bar{31},\bar{41} \,\}$$
is a subgroup of the multiplicative group $\left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^*$ , the question now , is there are a method to build the subgroup of $\left( \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\right)^*$ for every integer not null ??

Comment: Are you familiar with the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: i think yes , Chinese remainder theorem defines a ring isomorphism between the ring of integers modulo N and the direct product of the rings of integers modulo the ni. This means that for doing a sequence of arithmetic operations in Z/nZ, i think we can't using this theorem to buit the subgroup of the multiplicative group (Z/nZ)^*

Comment: The CRT also helps to express $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}^*$ as a product of cyclic groups of prime power order, and to express any subgroup of an arbitrary finite abelian group as a product of abelian groups of prime power order.

Comment: yes , please can you expain to me how i can  buit the subgroup of the multiplicative group (Z/50Z)^*

Comment: Bad example, $\Bbb{Z}/50\Bbb{Z}^*$ is cyclic with $20$ elements and generator $27$.

Comment: yes i know , but how i can build the subgroup of (Z/50Z)*